# Как с помощью JS сделать так чтоб атрибут "min" тега " input type='date' " установить на завтрашний день

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется поле input формата времени

```
<input type="date" id="time_do" name="user_do" min=" "/>
```

И я хочу сделать чтоб его атрибут min всегда был завтрашним днем, нашел решение для того чтобы устанавливать его на сегодняшний день с помощью js

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("time_do").setAttribute("min", today);
```

Но чтобы не делал и как бы не пытался не получается добавить +1 день к переменной "today"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
}

const date = new Date()
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)

const tomorrow = date.toLocaleString("ru", options).split('.').reverse().join('-')
document.getElementById("time_do").setAttribute("min", tomorrow)
```

```html
<input type="date" id="time_do" name="user_do" min=" "/>
```